# Python regex for property site size

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the size of a site from a property listing. Currently thinking `regex` is the best way to do it.

The property description is in the form:

1. "blah blah blah 0.5 of an acre blah blah blah"
2. "blah blah blah third of an acre blah blah blah"
3. "blah blah blah 3 acres blah blah blah"
4. "blah blah blah 1 acre blah blah blah"

What i'm after is a `regex`  pattern that can match two `groups`. The size of the site so in the above examples 0.5, third, 1, 3 and the size `metric` so in the above examples `"acre"`.

Currently ive got the regex expression:

```
    (^\d*[.,]?\d*) of an (acre)
```

which matches correctly on "0.5 of an acre" but fails on "blah blah blah 0.5 of an acre blah blah blah". I assume i'm missing something in the `regex` that ignores preceding and trailing words?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `^` at the start of the pattern anchors the match to the start of the string.  Remove it if you want to match anywhere in the string.  Then use `re.search` (and not `re.match`).

Comment: Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/byGgR4/5) is helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want something more robust, like the following:

```
(?:[\d./]+|third|quarter|half|one|two|three|four|five|ten|twenty)[\s-](?:\w+[\s-]){0,5}acres?
```

See the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4gpaHH/1) for the various types of matches it captures in addition to what you started with. The `(?:\w+[\s-]){0,5}` part matches up to 5 words between the number and "acre."

As @Tom Karzes said in the comments, be sure to use `re.search`. And for this type of situation you should also use the [re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) flag.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for all your example cases:

1. Captures digits or third, fourth, etc.
2. Optional, detects "of an" without capturing it.
3. Must have acre/s afterwards.

```
(\d+.?\d*|third|fourth|half)(?: of an)? acres?
```

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you have a number or a string (e.g. `third`) followed by the word "acre/s" or "of an acre".

If that is the case, then the regex to use would be something along the lines of:

`regex ([0-9\.]+|\w+) (?:of an )?acres?`

---

Here is a demo: https://rubular.com/r/zhr6kyT3UNnZsQ

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```regex
([\w\.]+) (?:(?:acres?)|(?:of an acre))
```

Check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/byGgR4/2/)

## Explanation

- `([\w\.]+)` - Captures fractions and word characters
- - Captures the space, duh
- `(?:(?:acres?)|(?:of an acre))` - Captures either

  - acre or acres
  - of an acre